# C# custom attributes - how to validate constructor's arguments?

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a custom attribute that defines some application version for a method:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
class ProjectConverterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Version BaseVersion { get; private set; }
    public Version TargetVersion { get; private set; }

    public ProjectConverterAttribute( string baseVersion, string targetVersion )
    {
        BaseVersion = new Version(baseVersion);
        TargetVersion = new Version(targetVersion);
    }
}
```

An instance of Version class can be initialized with a string representation: 
*"major.minor[.build[.revision]]"*

Now I can specify any string as a parameter and get the runtime exception caused by errors of parsing only when this code is executed by using Reflection methods:

```cs
[ProjectConverter( "1.0.1.215","1.0.1.R220")]
bool Convert( Project project )
{
}
```

**Is there a way to validate this value with highlighting in the code editor?**
Like it works for *AssemblyVersionAttribute* with the same version-formatted string as a parameter. It can be found in the file *Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs* .

```cs
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.904.2")]
```

If I try to exceed the value, this sting will be highlighted as an error at design time.

Comment: Why don't you use unit tests for this?

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks!, I will do that. But agree, the highlighting is more convenient.

Comment: Not for me, highlighting is annoying and also you are binding yourself to visual studio (remember that .net core is multiplatform). I would go for unit tests + continuous integration so as soon as a test fail you will know.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by writing your own custom Visual Studio Classifier Extension  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885492.aspx).